# Roslaunch without Rosout

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rosout, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're often running off some slow-to-write filesystems, so want to minimise logging once we're out in the wild...but still want some logging so that problems can be investigated after the fact.

Subsequently it would be good if we could avoid duplicating alot of the logging - once is sufficient even if its spread across multiple files. i.e. no aggregated rosout log and no stdout log either.

I'm not sure about the stdout log, but I can comment rosout in `roslaunch/roscore.xml`. Are there any side effects to doing this? And is there sufficient interest to consider proposing this as an optional argument to roslaunch?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10068/roslaunch-without-rosout/) by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3170 on 2011-05-25

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Modifying the roscore.xml is fine -- that's what it's there for.

Right now there is no option to disable logging in roslaunch.  I'd entertain suggestions (in ticket form) of potential ways to enable this (i.e. command-line syntaxes, environment variables, config files, etc...).

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2